# Reduce runtime with many subreports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2016 SP2 and writing queries (commands) for my main report which contains basic information about a property. It has 1 parameter, an account number.

I then have 11 subreports placed in various places on the main report.  One is in the report header, 3 are in Details a, 2 are in Details b, 4 in Details c and one in Details d.  The main report has information about a parcel of property. The subreports list details (one to many) based on the same parameter (account number).

I can link subreports on the account number field of the main report, but because there are 11 subreports the report reads all records in the various tables, then applies the filtering parameter after all are read.  With millions of records, and 11 passes at the DB (SQL SERVER 2008 R2), it takes well over a minute to return a report on one property.

I tried adding a parameter in the Edit Command for each subreport. That will run fast because it is applying the filter of account number before it reads all records. But then I am prompted 12 times for the same parameter. How can I reduce the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter fields in subreports should be used sparingly, if at all, for the reasons you've already discovered.  If the parameter field is the same across all subreports I would recommend you get the user to input the parameter on the main report only, then edit the links to the subreports to include the parameter from the main report.  This will allow you to effectively use the parameter field from the main report to filter the database results of each subreport without having to collect the parameter field on each subreport as user input.